# PHP Preg_match for authorized characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i'm a noob in regular expressions.
Il would like to prevent a form for special characters.

The characters auhorized are :

```
^#{}()<>|_æ+@%.,?:;"~\/=*$£€!
```

I made a preg_match rule that makes problems

```
if(preg_match("#[^#{}()<>|_æ+@%.,?:;"~\/=*$£€!]+#",$input)) $error=1;
```

I know that i should encapsulate special chars but i didn't know to achieve this.

Can you help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Escape `#`s in your regex single you chose it as a regex delimiter. And `"` as it is your string literal delimiter.

Comment: Is this correct ?
^\#{}()<>|_æ+@%.,?:;\"~\/=*$£€!

Comment: `preg_match('/[^#{}()<>|_æ+@%.,?:;"~\/=*$£€!]+/u', $input)`

Comment: Nice and quick ! Thank you so much

Comment: @FrançoisMacchi: are you sure it isn't a better option to build a pattern that describes the string from start to end with a character class of allowed characters (it may be more robust, take a look at the [unicode table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) if you are not convinced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match('/[^#{}()<>|_æ+@%.,?:;"~\/=*$£€!]+/u', $input)
```

Note:

- Using double quotation marks inside single-quoted string literals allows to avoid extra escaping
- When you use a specific char as a regex delimiter char, here you used `#`, you must escape this char inside the pattern.

**Note** `#` is safe to always escape since it is a special regex metacharacter when the `x` flag is used to enable comment/verbose/free-spacing mode (it is called in a lot of ways across regex references/libraries).

Also, since you are using chars from outside ASCII chars, it is  good idea to add `u` flag (to support Unicode strings as input).